# How to assign a value from prompt() in Javascript to asp.net Session, Cookie, Application, or any to pass that value to the next web form in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this script in the first web form in ASP.NET C#

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   function passJsValueFromPromptBoxToAspWebForm() {

       var input = prompt('Enter a value here: ');

       '<%Session["value"] = "' + input + '"; %>';
   }
</script>
```

It may be Session, Cookie, Application, or Context as long as I can store that input value to pass it to the second web form in ASP.NET. I need to use that input value in another web form.

The above Session["value"] only passes the string ' + input + ' to the next web form, not the input value from prompt() box. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do  that directly because javascript is client side and you can not directly access Server code from javascript you need to perform AJAX call to set the value as follows

JS code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> </script> <script type="text/javascript">
    function passJsValueFromPromptBoxToAspWebForm() {

  var input =  var input = prompt('Enter a value here: ');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'YOURFormNAME.aspx/SetSessionValue',
            data: '{ val:input  }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (newValue) {
                alert("Value set in session is " + newValue);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Write following method in your aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SetSessionValue(string val)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["value"] = val;
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["value"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have so far:

 function passJsValueFromPromptBoxToAspWebForm() {
  var value = prompt('Enter a number: ');
   switch (value) {
    case "1": window.location.href="http://www.google.com"; break;
    case "2": var input = prompt('Enter another number: ');
     .ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'hr.aspx',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             data: '{ id:input }', dataType: 'json',
             success: function(nV) { alert("..." + nV); } }); break;
    default: alert('Invalid'); break; }

It doesn't go to hr.aspx. Am I wrong?

Comment: @7d0 You are url is not matching. Your URL should be YOURPAGE.aspx/methodname. Like I have written url:'YOURFormNAME.aspx/SetSessionValue'. Note that SetSessionValue is my web-method in YOURFormNAME.aspx.cs